# Choosing dedicated server for Magento CE 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, server

I am thinking to rent following dedicated server for my Magento shop:

Intel XEON E5-1650v2 (6 x 3,5 GHz)
64 GB DDR3
2 x 1.000 GB SATA
Software-Raid
KVM Remote Management (iLO)

What I miss here is the SSD, DDR4 Ram and hardware Raid. My question is whether I need those mentioned and how big impact would they have on server performance, how much would the lack of hardware Raid and SSD reduce the performance of the dedicated server.

Second option is:

Intel i7-4790k 4.0 GHz
32GB DDR3 Ram
2 TB HDD or 2x 120 GB SSD
Hardware Raid for additional price otherwise SW Raid included

My concer here is that the CPU is not server graded but it is desktop CPU. I would rather have Xeon than the above but please help me give me some input.

Comment: What is your current traffic like ?

Comment: it is currently not much high traffic but I am doing some promotion which would increase the traffic and I would like to be prepared for future since you can't change the host and server often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, you would be able to get away with something like this:

CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1290 V2 (4 Cores x 3.7GHz)
RAM: 32GB DDR3 ECC
Disk Controller: RAID 1
Hard Drive: 2x 300GB 15000 RPM Seagate Cheetah SAS
Uplink Port Speed: 100mbps
Bandwidth: 10TB
Operating System: CentOS 6.6 - 64 Bit
Database Software: MySQL 5
IP Addresses: 3 IPs (1 Usable)
Network Attached Storage: 20gb NAS
KVM Over IP: IPMI 2.0 with integrated KVM over IP

This should be very competitive in performance and pricing.

Scott

Comment: looks good for good traffic website, for starting up i guess with be on a higher end.

Comment: Thank you Scott and Huzefam, The epecs  Scott posted are similar to what I would also cost me same as the option one above so I think I would go for the option one. I would also migrate to MariaDB from MySQL and to Varnish from Redis and to nginx from Apache server which I think will make the site pretty fast. I would like the load time to be no more than 2 sec. or less than that which I hope to achieve with the server option one. Thank you for your help.